# Form fields dependent on other other models require server restart

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class AlertForm(forms.Form):
    user_choices = sorted([(c.id, c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name) \
        for c in User.objects.all()], key=lambda user: user[1])
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    recipients = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=user_choices,
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size':'20'}),
        help_text="You will automatically be included with the recipients.")
```

The problem is that if I add a user to the database using the admin interface or any other method, I have to restart the server before the newly added user will appear in the MultipleChoiceField.  How can I avoid the server restart?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to calculate your `choices` dynamically, you need to do so in the `__init__` method of your form rather than in the form definition.  Remember that the body of a class is only executed once when the class definition is loaded--that's why a server restart fixes your problem.

You'll want something like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AlertForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    user_choices = sorted([(c.id, c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name) \
        for c in User.objects.all()], key=lambda user: user[1])
    self.fields['recipients'].choices = user_choices
```

You could also probably condense that into a queryset using aggregation, `order_by`, and  `values` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

In my searching I found a far simpler solution:  [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield).  It's implemented like this:

```
class AlertForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

This form field handles all the details including dynamically updating the recipients field.

Comment: Note that that doesn't do exactly what your question was asking: the choice text will be the value of the `__unicode__` or `__string__` method on your `User` class (by default just the `username`, not "<first_name> <last_name>" as is in your question.  The sort order will also fall back to the model's default, rather than the one you were using.